# How to clear CMake cache in Clion?

Tags: cmake, clion

I am currently trying to swap static libraries in one of my projects which requires swapping find_package() commands for explicit links to static libraries. One of the problems I encountered is that even after deleting find_package() commands reloading the CMake Project the old variables are still present.

Is there a way to explicitly flush the CMake cache other than manually deleting all files from the temporary folder Clion creates for building the project?

Comment: You don't have to delete all the files, just the CMakeCache.txt file.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Starting with CLion 1.5 144.3143 (2016-01-20), you can clear the cmake cache *without* loosing the CLion indexes and *without* restarting (meaning: very fast, also on huge projects):

```
Tool | CMake | "Reset cache and reload project".
```

If that for some reasons is not enough, or if you have an older CLion, you can do the more radical:

```
File | "Invalidate Caches / Restart"
```

and click on "Invalidate and restart".

EDITS

- 2016-01-20: add the faster method available with newer CLion.

Comment: The message explicitly states this, but just be aware that this clears your local history. If you don't want to do this, you can try Cristian Bidea's suggestion to delete the CMakeCache.txt

Comment: Note that "Invalidate and restart" will delete the cache for all of your CLion projects, not just the currently open one.  Also, sometimes I've had to manually cleanup the residue left after this operation and/or re-import projects.

Comment: For me using CLion 1.1 on Windows, deleting CMakeCache.txt prevents the project from building until the file is restored.

Comment: Have updated Mac OS X El Capitan then encountered the issue that: "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk" path not found so this command solved the issue! Thanks.

Comment: I did a "reset cache and reload project", and now clion no longer calls cmake to regenerate make files: `Error:ERROR null: No cmake script provided. ERROR null: Problem processing arguments. Aborting.` Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: @DaveFar: You followed suggestion 1. My answer says: "if that for some reasons is not enough, ..." Did you try suggestion 2 ?

Comment: @marco.m: yes, I also tried suggestion 2, and it did not solve my problems, i.e. i still get the same ERROR message.

Answer (score 1):

There is some magic with this cache. 
I got bad value for one variable once: by some reason cmake found some wrecked freetype includes inside `mono.framework` (another reason to dislike mono...) and tried to use them to compile my project. Obviously compilation failed.

I tried to remove `CMakeCache.txt` and rebuild project but incorrect path come back. Even after I removed `mono.framework` dir!

The solution was to remove incorrect line from the cache and restart the build. After that cmake got the correct path and build succeded.

**UPD:**
After I "reload cmake project" incorrect value came back. Deleting everything in `$HOME/Library/Caches/clion11/cmake/generated/` dir (for OS X) seems to finally solve the issue.