# How to switch between GCC and Clang in Clion from within CMakeLists.txt using windows/cygwin

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, clion

I put

```
 set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER           "/usr/bin/clang.exe")
```

Run/Clean, Run/Build.

I get link errors like:

```
undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
: undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
```

Presumably there are other variables to change. Tried adding `-lstdc++` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, but no different.

Is there a CLion way as opposed to a CMake way, for example?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `--stdlib=libstdc++` with clang.

Comment: the `C++` compiler is called `clang++`, you're using the `C` compiler

Comment: Please don't hardcode compilers in `CMakeLists.txt`. Use the commandline options `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=...` and `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=...` instead.

Answer (score 13):

Specifying a compiler with CMake is a bit delicate. Although the method you are using, setting CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER in CMakeLists.txt works, it is the least-recommended way in the [CMake FAQ](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F).

CLion supports method 2 of the [CMake FAQ](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F): using `-D` within the cmake invocation. Setting the variables in CMakeLists.txt has no effect.

On Mac, go to `Preferences`

On Linux/Windows, go to `File | Settings`

then `Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake | CMake options` and enter the text:

```
-D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/path/to/c_compiler
-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/path/to/c++_compiler
```

See the [CLion FAQ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/) for details.

Note also that when you change compilers, you will have to invalidate the CLion cmake cache and restart, see my answer on [How to clear CMake cache in Clion?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28309498/561422).

EDIT

After I wrote this answer, CLion added support for multiple build directories, as pointed out by @rubenvb in the comments. This is another path to investigate.

Comment: There may be issues getting this to work in the latest version of CLion: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-7800

Comment: Note that you can have two separate build directories (one per compiler) so the switching becomes a lot less painful and a full rebuild isn't needed each time you switch.

Comment: Instead of writing a path for me it worked if I just wrote "clang". (writing the path did not work for me).

Answer (score 0):

In fact the latest version of Clions 2018.2 running on windows 10 environment work with LLVM clang version 6 /6.0.1 or even 7.0 along with   GCC mingw x64 win32 specific  variant.

linker default is set to GCC not visual studio

I guess it should work on cygwin too with the same setup as the following also tested to work on a number of popular c++ IDE also.

x64 or 32 specific GCC mingw version tested to work on Clions 2018.2

\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0 or mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0

CMake build setup as below

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(project_name )

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "c:/llvm/bin/clang.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "c:/llvm/bin/clang++.exe")
// target i686-pc-windows-gnu for 32bit 
set(CL_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-v -target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++17")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CL_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )
add_executable(project_name   yourcpp.cpp)
```