# Refresh CMakeLists.txt in clion

Tags: cmake, clion

In the following section of the main CMakeLists.txt file,

```
# Allow builds to complete with warnings (do not set -Werror)
option(CIVETWEB_ALLOW_WARNINGS "Do not stop build if there are warnings" OFF)
message(STATUS "Build if there are warnings - ${CIVETWEB_ALLOW_WARNINGS}")
```

when I switch `CIVETWEB_ALLOW_WARNINGS` to `ON`, I still get the message

> -- Build if there are warnings - OFF

even if I use "reload the cmake project" in clion.

Using cmake from the command line, the output is correctly

> -- Build if there are warnings - ON

What do I have to do in clion such that cmake changes are refreshed correctly?

---

UPDATE 1:

I changed in clion's cmake cache `CIVETWEB_ALLOW_WARNINGS` to `ON`, but I still get

```
error: macro name is a reserved identifier [-Werror,-Wreserved-id-macro]
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* for setgroups() */
```

---

UPDATE 2:

The following lines from CMakeLists.txt are also relevant for `-Werror`:

```
if (NOT CIVETWEB_ALLOW_WARNINGS)
  add_c_compiler_flag(-Werror)
endif()
```

and

```
if (NOT CIVETWEB_ALLOW_WARNINGS)
    add_cxx_compiler_flag(-Werror)
endif()
```

However, note that `${CIVETWEB_ALLOW_WARNINGS}` in the message above is already evaluated to `OFF` in clion and to `ON` on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you have two problems.

Firstly, there's the issue of "Changing an option in cmake doesn't lead to the option really changing". That's caused by [CMakeCache being annoying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526039/how-to-clear-cmake-cache-in-clion).

Now you solved that by changing the CMakeCache by hand (instead of clearing it and doing "reload CMake project"), you have a second problem: your flag doesn't work. I assume that flag is supposed to stop `-Werror` being passed to the compiler, but we can see from your error message that this is still happening. Without seeing more of the CMakeLists.txt I can't be more help on that one. Perhaps you're having trouble with [removing flags from CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344564/cmake-remove-a-compile-flag-for-a-single-translation-unit)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Chris (+1). Yes, you are right, I have two problems. I did solve the cache problem, but not the second problem. I added UPDATE 2 to my question in relation to the second problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Now CLion has a "Reset Cache and Reload Project" option. (as of CLion 2020.1 or 2019.3, not sure as of older versions)

It is located in: CMake Tab -> Gear icon on the left pane under the green "Reload CMake Project" -> red recycle-button "Reset Cache and Reload Project":
[image: CLion Reset Cache and Reload Project]

Caution, this will delete your built binaries, forcing you to rebuild a project.

2. On older versions you can delete `cmake-build-debug`/`cmake-build-release` directories and trigger "Reload CMake Project". This have almost the same effect as 1).
3. If you don't want to rebuild your project afterwards, you can delete file `CMakeCache.txt` from `cmake-build-debug`/`cmake-build-release` directory and trigger "Reload CMake Project" from CMake tab.

Edit (25 Jul 2021)

4. You can go to your CMake output (by default it is called something like this: `cmake-build-*`) folder, open the `CMakeCache.txt` file, look for the option you are interested in and swith it from `OPTION=ON` to `OPTION=OFF` and then press "Reload CMake Project".