# why does CLion have a stale library dependency?

Tags: linker, ide, clion, build-dependencies

Update our CMakeLists.txt to change the version of pcre. The library name changes from libpcre.dylib to libpcre2-8.dylb. When I rebuild in CLion 1.2.4 I get an error at link time:
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `/Users/ghendrey/XXX/current/lib/libpcre.dylib', needed by`src/main/XXX'.  Stop.

Answer (score 0):

CLion keeps a cache and the cache was stale. Deleting the cache solved the problem, as described here:

[How to clear CMake cache in Clion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526039/how-to-clear-cmake-cache-in-clion)

Comment: Also note that this is the way CMake's [find_package](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#Performance_and_caching) works, not just in CLion.